# Bash script to isolate words in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

Here is my initial input data to be extracted:

```
david ex1=10 ex2=12 quiz1=5 quiz2=9 exam=99
judith ex1=8 ex2=16 quiz1=4 quiz2=10 exam=90
sam ex1=8 quiz1=5 quiz2=11 exam=85
song ex1=8 ex2=20 quiz2=11 exam=87
```

How do extract each word to be formatted in this way:

```
david 
ex1=10
ex2=12
etc...
```

As I eventually want to have output like this:

```
david 12 99
judith 16 90
sam 0 85
song 20 87
```

when I run my program with the commands:

```
./marks ex2 exam < file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposed your input file is named `input.txt`, just replace *space char* by *new line char* using [tr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29) command line tool:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < input.txt
```

For your second request, you may have to extract specific field on each line, so the `cut` and `awk` commands may be useful (note that my example is certainly improvable):

```
while read p; do
  echo -n "$(echo $p | cut -d ' ' -f1) "                  # name
  echo -n "$(echo $p | cut -d ' ' -f3 | cut -d '=' -f2) " # ex2 val
  echo -n $(echo $p | awk -F"exam=" '{ print  $2 }')      # exam val
  echo
done < input.txt
```

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat): `tr ' ' '\n' < input.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This script does what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$@
awk -v a="$a" -F'[[:space:]=]+' '
BEGIN {
    split(a, b) # split field names into array b
}
{
    printf "%s ", $1 # print first field
    for (i in b) { # loop through fields to search for
        f = 0 # unset "found" flag
        for (j=2; j<=NF; j+=2) # loop though remaining fields, 2 at a time
            if ($j == b[i]) { # if field matches value in array
                printf "%s ",$(j+1)
                f = 1 # set "found" flag
            }
        if (!f) printf "0 " # add 0 if field not found
    }
    print "" # add newline
}' file
```

Testing it out

```
$ ./script.sh ex2 exam
david 12 99
judith 16 90
sam 0 85
song 20 87
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer unfortunately I cannot use AWK

Comment: Seems like a strange requirement, since awk is the right tool for the job. This would be fairly simple to implement in native bash but I don't see the advantage.